# Is there a way to shorten an ANSI output or change it entirely for .format() spacing

Tags: python, python-3.x, ansi-escape, string.format

I'm trying to add color to values in a formatted table, but the spacing is acting strange and spacing based off of the characters instead of the format spacing I input.
dictionary:

```
items = {
'staff'     : ['Staff',          20, 0,'Yes', 'None', 'None', 'None', ' ',  5,12],
'club'      : ['Club',           75, 0,'Yes', 'None', 'None', 'None', ' ', 15,22],
'mace'      : ['Mace',           200,0,'Yes', 'None', 'None', 'None', ' ', 30,371],
'warhammer' : ['Warhammer',      350,0,'Yes', 'None', 'None', 'None', ' ', 50,60]
}
```

argv = 'staff', 'club', 'mace', 'warhammer'

code in question:

```
def color(r, g, b, text):
    return str("\033[38;2;{};{};{}m{} \033[38;2;255;255;255m".format(r, g, b, text))
x = 0
i = 1
print("{:<0} {:<12} {:<10} {:<10} {:<6}".format(" ", "Item", "Cost", "Damage", "Owned"))
while x < i - 1:
    y = listing(x, argv, False, 0,1,8,9,3) #outputs a list from a dictionary
    if y[1] > player['coins']:
        y[1] = color(255,0,0,(y[1]))
    else:
        y[1] = color(0,255,0,(y[1]))
    z = options.get(x+1) #gets an arrow for selection, not important for this code
    w = {z:y}
    for k, v in w.items():
        item, cost, damagemin, damagemax, owned = v
        print("{:<0} {:<12} {:<6} {:>03d}-{:>03d}    {:<5}".format(k, item, cost, damagemin, damagemax, owned))
    x += 1
```

it outputs this without the coin color check.

```
  Item         Cost   Damage     Owned 
> Staff        20     005-012    Yes   
  Club         75     015-022    Yes   
  Mace         200    045-055    Yes   
  Warhammer    350    075-090    Yes   
  Back
```

But when I add the coin check to change the color, it outputs this:

```
  Item         Cost   Damage     Owned 
> Staff        20  005-012    Yes      
  Club         75  015-022    Yes      
  Mace         200  045-055    Yes     
  Warhammer    350  075-090    Yes     
  Back
```

I've checked what it changes the value of y[1] to and it returns `'\x1b[38;2;0;255;0m20 \x1b[38;2;255;255;255m'`
I'm at a complete loss for how to fix this.

Comment: You can't include those "invisible" characters in your column count.  It takes a fair amount of work to do that properly.  You can insert the invisible strings, but use a separate format for them, like `"{}{:<6}{}"`..  I don't see where `y` is being printed here.

Comment: `y` is being used to grab the items I need for the display. Then the code updates a temporary dictionary so that the `for` loop works as intended. If I need to I can also give the `listing()` function, but all the listing function does is return a list from my desired data points.

Comment: I'm suggesting you add a slot before and after your "cost", initialized to empty.  Then plug in the "color" and "end color" when you need them.  Print those with `{}`, since they will take no display space

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is

```
while x < i - 1:
    y = listing(x, argv, False, 0,1,8,9,3)
    if y[1] > player['coins']:
        r,g,b = 255,0,0
    else:
        r,g,b = 0,255,0
    z = options.get(x+1)
    w = {z:y}
    for k, v in w.items():
        item, cost, damagemin, damagemax, owned = v
        print("{:<0} {:<12} \033[38;2;{};{};{}m{:<5} \033[38;2;255;255;255m {:>03d}-{:>03d}    {:<5}".format(k, item, r,g,b, cost, damagemin, damagemax, owned))
    x += 1
```

After research on the `.format()` function of Python and the way Python reads it, there isn't a way (as far as I know, please correct me if I'm wrong) to fix this in a way for variable spacing amount in the `"{}".format()`. So due to that, I need to break apart `\033[38;2;{};{};{}m{} \033[38;2;255;255;255m` into its separate parts and manually insert them into the `.format()`.
The problem with the formatting is that `m{}` was effectively overriding the `{:<6}` in the `"{}".format()`. So in order to fix that, I broke `\033[38;2;{};{};{}m{} \033[38;2;255;255;255m` into `\033[38;2;{};{};{}m{}` and `\033[38;2;255;255;255m`. While this is less than optimal, it does fix the problem.

In `\033[38;2;{};{};{}m{}`, the first 3 `{}` accept values 0-255 (in this specific case) while `m{}` accepted text. Since all of this is in the `"".format()`, all of the `{}` still accept formatting arguments. So after inserting the color code into the `"".format()`.

```
print("{:<0} {:<12} \033[38;2;{};{};{}m{:<5} \033[38;2;255;255;255m {:>03d}-{:>03d}    {:<5}".format(k, item, r,g,b, cost, damagemin, damagemax, owned))
```

I added `m{:<5}` to format the text, fixing the problem entirely.

Now to account for this, I changed

```
if y[1] > player['coins']:
    y[1] = color(255,0,0,(y[1]))
else:
    y[1] = color(0,255,0,(y[1]))
```

Which ran the color function and returned an ANSI string that was not able to be formatted. Which then I changed to

```
if y[1] > player['coins']:
    r,g,b = 255,0,0
else:
    r,g,b = 0,255,0
```

Which changes/adds new variables `r,g,b` that will be inserted directly into the `.format()` function.
This effectively is just expanding the original `color()` function and inserting it directly into the `.format()`.

Comment: `@Tim Roberts` is the one who gave me the idea to separate the code in `.format()`. I'm just the one who made it work with my code specifically, all answer credit should go to him.